# Using 'equation split', how can I ensure that only the last equation is numbered?

Tags: equations, amsmath, split

Consider the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & = b + c \\ & = c + d \\ & = d + e
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which outputs

[image]

I want to do this so that the equation label (39) is only attached the the final equation, d+e.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Should placing the equation number next to the last row be done for all multi-row equations, or should this be done on a case by case basis?

Comment: It should be done for all multi-row equations. It's bad practice to have multiple equations numbered with the same reference, which would technically be the case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to load `amsmath` with the `tbtags` option:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & = b + c \\ & = c + d \\ & = d + e
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

(Note: `twocolumn` is just for making a smaller picture.)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `tbtags` option for `amsmath` does just that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & = b + c \\ & = c + d \\ & = d + e
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you'd want to place equation numbers to the left (with option `leqno`), they'll go to the top of `split` automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a `{split}` environment, use an `{aligned}[b]` environment; no other changes needed.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
a & = b + c \\ & = c + d \\ & = d + e
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{align}
a & = b + c \nonumber\\ & = c + d \nonumber\\ & = d + e
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead split (which has one number vertical centered) you should use `align` where you allow to number only last line of equation:

```
\begin{align}
a & = b + c \notag   \\ 
  & = c + d \notag   \\ 
  & = d + e
\end{align}
```